# amCharts is adding 3 hours (UTC-3) to date objects

Tags: amcharts

I'm getting JSON data to build a chart using AMCHARTS.

The graph is ok.

Problem is, when I add a listener to a click event in the graph and try to extract the date (axis X), it automatically adds 3 hours because I'm in Buenos Aires and have UTC-3.

Don't have idea where or how to set the UTC -3 offset. Any help provided will be really useful.

I'm getting the date information like this:

```
"listeners": [{
            "event": "clickGraphItem",
            "method": function(e) {
                var item = e.item.serialDataItem.category;
                console.log(item);
```

*Another option would be to set Date: off so i get a string data type instead of a date object.*

Comment: Have you tried looking at other properties in e.item.serialDataItem. You could probably find your original data string (as given in your dataProvider) by looking at e.item.serialDataItem.dataContext.

Comment: Are the dates values from the `Date` type in your data or just strings? Could you show what you have in the `dataProvider`?